# PHP-SQL. Non-recursive way to select Categories and multiple Subcategories from DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a way to get every subcategory from a parent category, in my case, I dont know how many subcategories I will have, so, the only solution I found is using recursion.

I used:

```
public function recursiveSel(&$tree, $db, $parent = 0){
    $query = $db->query("SELECT id, catName FROM categories WHERE parentCategory=".$parent);

    while($category = $db->fetch_array($query)){
        $tree .= $category['catName'];
        if($category['id'] != $parent){
            $this->treeSelCategories($tree,$db,$category['id']);
        }
    }
}
```

But I think that if 1000 users are navegating through the categories and I have 500 categories, it can be a mess.

My category table is builted like this:

```
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|| id || name    || parent ||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|| 1  || games   ||  0     ||
|| 2  || courses ||  0     ||
|| 3  || cooking ||  2     ||
|| 4  || diy     ||  2     ||
|| 5  || action  ||  1     ||
|| 6  || new     ||  5     ||
|| 7  || tutorial||  3     ||
|| 8  || easy    ||  7     ||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

And the result needed:

```
games
--action
----new
courses
--cooking
----tutorial
------easy
--diy
```

Is there a way to do it without use recursion? Only with sql maybe?
I can change the db structure if is needed.

Thank you!

Comment: It is inherently recursive, the answer is no. Cache it...

Comment: you can perhaps add a field like "topParent" or "root" and always save it when adding a new row ?

Comment: AS winmutt says: no. There is no solution without recursive when you have unlimited dept in the structure. If you are afraid of the database load you can always cache the data. Another option is to save the full path to your category in the table like `games/action/new/` and read/compare this full string when opening a category or creating the menu. That way, the only time you use recursive category selection is when adding or deleting a record.

Comment: @djoosi Thanks for your answer, but, if I use topParent as the id of the rear parent, it will be always 0. Maybe I understood wrongly.

Comment: I'll try adding the path, Thank you Joshua !